# permission denied while making a file without asking for password

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm trying to create a file using `cat > list` but each time it shows me "Permission denied".

```
xyz@jaishreeram:/home$ sudo cat > list
bash: l: Permission denied
xyz@jaishreeram:/home$ sudo cat > list
bash: l: Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you want to make a file called "list"?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This is vague and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please be a little bit more specific or detailed about what you're trying to accomplish, or take a look at [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 17):

try

```
sudo bash -c 'cat file1 >> file2'
```

or

```
cat file1 | sudo tee -a file2
```

read [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1370034) in [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1370034)

Answer (score 4):

The location you are writing into required super user privileges. However, the way you are writing into the file does not assume this. For this either log in as root using `su` and then write using `cat > list` or do `sudo vi list`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't make a file using `cat`. You have to use `echo` instead. So just run this to make a file called "list":

> echo > list

If you need root privileges you first have autenticate as root using
`su -`
now you can `echo > list`
now you can logout as root using `logout`

**This because the redirect is done before sudo starts, that's why you get "permission denied" without being asked for password.**

`cat` is used to concatenate files and print on the standard output.
`echo` is used to display a line of text, using the "> file_name" you will redirect that line of text to "file_name" and if "file_name" doesn't exist, the file will be created.

PS: There are tons of method to make a new file using the command line but, in my opinion, this's the faster and easier to remember.

Comment: xyz@jaishreeram:/home$ echo > list
bash: list: Permission denied

Comment: My bad, if you need root privileges, you have to use `echo` as root, because the redirect is done before sudo starts

Comment: **Side note:** You can write into files using the way the question has been posted, the problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple, you don't have permissions to write into the `/home` directory since it owned by root.

```
/home$ ls -la .
total 36
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root          root           4096 Apr 19 05:03 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root          root           4096 Sep 24 09:49 ..
```

You should use the same command but in "your home" directory. Your home directory is the user directory under `/home`:

```
/home$ ls -la .
total 36
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root          root           4096 Apr 19 05:03 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root          root           4096 Sep 24 09:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 70 braiam        braiam         4096 Sep 29 10:06 braiam
```

You have several ways to go to your home directory:

- Run `cd` without any parameter.
- Run `cd ~` or `cd $HOME`
- Open another new terminal
- Use `cd /home/yourusername` to go to your personal directory.